# Animate.css Messing Up My Site

Tags: html, css, viewport, visual-glitch

I've been toying around with animate.css and it has completely messed up my website. I'm not sure of the cause at all. Also I would like the animation to only happen when the div is in the view-port and I'm not sure how to do so.

https://road-aware.herokuapp.com/

Comment: I think the problem is that your `div` which you animate has `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` and bounceInDown animation uses translate3d.

Comment: How would I go about combating the problem? Even when I remove the transform, it still has a horizontal bar and most of the problems.

Comment: @RileyKinsella see my answer for a working solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `.landing-container` to:

```
.landing-container {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  padding: 15px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 80%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

Changing the `position` makes sure the element centers vertically. Removing `left: 50%` and adding `margin: auto` centers it horizontally. Adding the `display: block` makes the two above possible.

Comment: this seems to work, although with 50% it doesn't seem to be center, I changed it to 30% and it seems okay. Can you help with the animation only going off on scroll?

Comment: 50% was something you had decided to use... For me the animation is triggered on load.

Comment: Right! Do you know how to trigger it on scroll?

Comment: For that you would need to use Javascript, it's out of the scoop for this question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to just override default animate.css behaviour. Because you already use transform in your css and animate.css overrides your css. ;)

See this [jsfiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/samuells/0ez3s8pa/1/)

It's without browser prefixes, but that should be not big deal. ;)

```
@keyframes bounceInDown {
  from, 60%, 75%, 90%, to {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  }

  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -3000px, 0);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -40%, 0);
  }

  75% {
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -60%, 0);
  }

  90% {
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -45%, 0);
  }

  to {
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use overflow: hidden

```html
<style type="text/css">
.examplediv {
    background-color:#efefef;
    border-style:solid #000000 1px;
}

#divid {
    position:absolute;
    left:450px; top:350px; width:35000px; height:35000px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
</style>

<body>

  <div id="divid" class="examplediv">
  ...
  </div>
```

widthout

```css
.examplediv
     {
      background-color:#efefef;
      border-style:solid #000000 1px;
        
     }
    #divid
    {
     position:absolute;
     left:450px; top:350px; width:35000px; height:35000px;
    
    }
```

```html
    <body>

      <div id="divid" class="examplediv">

      </div>
```

http://www.css4you.de/overflow.html

Comment: This answer is really vague and hard to follow. I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: width overflow hidden you can deactivate your scrollbars then you can set the text a bit to the left